# Correct Way To Add/Reference an Open Source Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I'm planning to use this project: [MQTTnet](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet) withing my own project.

I've just downloaded the project from GIT. I currently only know how to add classes by reference, one-by-one. It doesn't feel right to me. There must be a more correct way to referencing the entire project in my own project.

1) WHAT is the best/preferred way to work with an open source library like above and 
2) HOW do you do it in visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

You should use nuget to add and manage dependencies. Unless you want to make any modifications to the open source libraries code, you should just add binaries. Nuget will also inform you about latest versions available to upgrade.

Check this - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MQTTnet/ for the package you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the downloaded Project to your own solution by following this guide

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460187.aspx (To add an existing project to a solution)
2. Add a reference to this newly added project to your existing project

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx (Project-to-Project References)